# Ways to allow other users to upload images and text

Tags: html, image, blogs

I've decided to make a website for my friend as sort of picture diary and I having trouble figuring out how I can make it so he is able to upload images and some text without having to go into the html for the website and doing it that way i'm looking for simple text editor like when you are typing up a question on here and basically a photo blog.

Thanks for taking the time to read this sorry for the rambling i'm having trouble describing it

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: So you want `<textarea>` where you can type and add images etc

Comment: Joe at the moment I don't I'm just looking for ways & ideas on how I can make this site and upload these images and Sanoj thank you I will try this now and see if this is what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since you have not yet tried anything i will give you**  [link](http://www.tinymce.com/) try

### [Must Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: this is perfect thank you it's just what I needed and I am very sorry for not formatting the question properly and I will keep that in mind for the future

Comment: @DanCliff not only formatting you must add code what you tried

Answer (score 0):

Create a web app with `<textarea>` and upload button where the user copy and pastes the text that goes with the image.

Or save the text file on local machine and create a Batch file to execute the upload using FTP with a command line utility like PSCP.

```
RUN('CMD /c ' & i#  & ' & ECHO ON & pscp -v -p -pw password localPath_FileName userName@example.com:/home/userName/xxx/yyy/ & EXIT',1)
```

Where /xxx/yyy/ is the path to save on the server.
and localPath_FileName is the location of the document and or photo on the local machine.

The create a script to process the uploaded doc/pic.